# Why is maven automatically adding multiple versions of Jackson-databind

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, jackson, pom.xml

I am currently using spring-boot version 1.5.22.RELEASE and I am trying to upgrade my Jackson-databind dependency's version( currently 2.8.11.3 ) in my pom-file to the latest one( 2.12.3 ) ,but even after mvn clean install I see two jars for Jackson databind i.e. both the versions 2.8.11.3 and 2.12.3 ,why is this happening,is it because version 2.12.3 is not supported by spring boot 1.5.22.RELEASE ?Have also tried Downgrading it to 2.5.1 and I still have multiple versions (2.5.1 and 2.8.11.3) of Jackson databind.( Please note that I have excluded Jackson databind in from the components that require it like spring-boot-starter-web and made Jackson-databind as a direct dependency)

Comment: What do you mean by "I see two jars for Jackson databind"? Where exactly are you looking?

Comment: Upgrade to most recent versions of Spring Boot...the 1.X lines is long time EoL...

Comment: @JFabianMeier  By "I see two jars for Jackson databind", I meant that under my external libraries i see both maven: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.11.3 and maven: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3 i.e 2 versions of Jackson-databind

Comment: @khmarbaise its a very big repo and it's not possible to update the spring-boot version,for now i am just trying to figure out if jackson-databind:2.12.3 is supported by Spring-boot v1.5.22.RELEASE

Comment: What do you mean by "my external libraries"? Are both versions of jackson-databind in the final JAR or WAR that your are creating?

Comment: @JFabianMeier sorry i am kinda new to spring so i'm kinda bad with theese terms,in intellij,under projects there is a dropdown called "external libraries" which has all the Jar files imported by maven so i have both jackson-databind:2.8.11.3.jar and jackson-databind:2.12.3.jar present

Comment: This may also be a wrong list generated by IntelliJ. use `mvn dependency:list` to see the actual list of dependencies.

Comment: @JFabianMeier So does this mean and confirm that jackson-databind:2.12.3 is not supported by  spring boot 1.5.22.RELEASE

Comment: No. It just means that the dependency in your final JAR or WAR is the version 2.8.11.3. It does not say anything about supported versions.

Comment: @JFabianMeier oh wait sorry my bad i can see both of them ```[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.3:compile -- module com.fasterxml.jackson.databind``` and ```com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.11.3:compile -- module jackson.databind (auto)```

Comment: This is from the `mvn dependency:list` ?

Comment: yeah i am getting both the versions

Comment: Maybe this has to do with using Java modules. But I am not sure. You should ask a separate question including the output of `mvn dependency:list`

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67423523/why-are-two-versions-for-jackson-databind-being-shown-when-i-execute-mvn-depende?noredirect=1#comment119174378_67423523)