# Why are two versions for Jackson-databind being shown when I execute mvn dependency:list

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jackson, pom.xml, parent-pom

I am currently using spring-boot version 1.5.22.RELEASE and I am trying to upgrade my Jackson-databind dependency's version( currently 2.8.11.3 ) in my pom-file to the latest one( 2.12.3 ) ,but even after
`mvn clean install`,When i execute `mvn dependency:list` I get both the versions I.e. 2.8.11.3 and 2.12.3 -

`[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.3:compile -- module com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`

and

`[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.11.3:compile -- module jackson.databind (auto)`

Why is this happening,is it because version 2.12.3 is not supported by spring boot 1.5.22.RELEASE ?Have also tried Downgrading it to 2.5.1 and I still have multiple versions (2.5.1 and 2.8.11.3) of Jackson databind.( Please note that I have excluded Jackson databind in from the components that require it like spring-boot-starter-web and made Jackson-databind as a direct dependency)

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Hey @JFabianMeier I'm using Java 8

Comment: @JFabianMeier does the (auto) for jackson-databind 2.8.11.3 mean anything? ```[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.11.3:compile -- module jackson.databind (auto) ```

Comment: This all looks like java modules, about which I know only very little..